# como hacer un incremento al valor de una imagen en la url en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, dom

Hola tengo el siguiente código, el caso es que no me incrementa i al recorrerlo con img y añadiendolo a p1, como podría hacerlo correctamente para que vaya sumando uno en cada iteración y que vaya mostrando dicha imagen correspondiente ? gracias de antemano.

```js
var div1 = document.createElement("div");
div1.setAttribute("id", "div1");
var div2 = document.createElement("div");
div2.setAttribute("id", "div2");
var div3 = document.createElement("div");
div3.setAttribute("id", "resultado");

document.body.appendChild(div1);
document.body.appendChild(div2);
document.body.appendChild(div3);

    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    let data = [];

    let url1 = 'https://reqres.in/api/users';

    xhttp.open('GET',url1,true);
    xhttp.send();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            let datos = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

            // aquí solo agregué ['data']
            console.log(datos['data']);

            let resultado = document.querySelector('#resultado');
            resultado.innerHTML = '';
            
            //len variable donde guardo tamaño del array datos['data'] 
            len = datos['data'].length;
            //cambié a un for tradicional
            for(let i = 0 ; i < len ; i++){
              //igualo la variable item a la correspondiente iteración 
              let item = datos['data'][i];
              [item.first_name,item.last_name];

                var div = document.createElement('div');
                var p0 = document.createElement('p');
                var p1 = document.createElement('p');
                
                p1.setAttribute("id","fotos");

                
                var hr = document.createElement('hr');
                p0.innerHTML = item.first_name+" "+item.last_name;
                
                

                var img = document.createElement("img");
                img.setAttribute("src", item.avatar)
                document.getElementById("fotos");
                
                p1.appendChild(img);


                
                div.appendChild(hr);
                div.appendChild(p0)
                div.appendChild(p1);

                resultado.appendChild(div);
            }

        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ejercicio 3</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="api.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema está en esta parte

```js
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.setAttribute("src", "https://reqres.in/img/faces/1-image.jpg")
```

Creas el elemento y le asignas el atributo de manera hardcodeada

```js
//prueba con esto
img.setAttribute("src", item.avatar)
```

Comment: gracias @alejandro00 en un momento lo pruebo !

Comment: funciona correctamente la doy por válida !

Comment: dejo la respuesta editada para que le sirva a alguien de ayuda un saludo y gracias !